# How do I zoom into Google Maps with just javascript?

Tags: javascript

I’m challenging myself to navigate Google Maps (http://maps.google.com) without my mouse and just by entering commands into Chrome Developer Console.

I found that the class name of the main canvas that Google Maps uses is `widget-scene-canvas`, and I’ve successfully obtained that canvas with

```
document.getElementsByClassName('widget-scene-canvas')[0]
```

Hence, I tried to trigger a click event to zoom in with

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 300, 300, 300, 300, false, false, false, false, 0,
    document.getElementsByClassName('widget-scene-canvas')[0]);
document.body.dispatchEvent(evt);
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 300, 300, 300, 300, false, false, false, false, 0,
    document.getElementsByClassName('widget-scene-canvas')[0]);
document.body.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

However, it doesn’t even seem like Google Maps is detecting a click.

What am I doing wrong? Anyone other adventurous people want to give this a shot?

Comment: use the panTo and setZoom methods

Comment: On what object? I'm not using the API. I'm just messing with real Google Maps.

Comment: Any ideas for moving the map around?

Comment: oh. sorry i misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking clicks on the zoom buttons in *vanilla*

```
function zoom(out) {
    document.querySelector('.widget-zoom-' + (out ? 'out' : 'in')).click();
}

zoom();
setTimeout(zoom.bind(null, true), 1e3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

**Zoom in:** `$(".widget-zoom-in").click();`

**Zoom out:** `$(".widget-zoom-out").click();`